# @autoreleasepool crashes program with seg fault

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, gnustep

I've just installed GNUstep, libobjc2, and llvm on a ubuntu 14.04 box using [this script](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/GNUstep_under_Ubuntu_Linux).  The installation works for most objective-c2.0 features but not for arc.  If I run the following simple program, it crashes as soon as it executes @autoreleasepool with a segmentation fault.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool{
NSLog(@"autoreleasepool works...\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with the -fobjc-arc flag.  Any suggestions?  I've spent two days on this searching the internet.  If I use NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init] the program runs.

Mark Allyn